# Windows run job by id right 'now'

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, at

Can one run a scheduled command by id 'right now' ?

I'm not sure if it is even possible on windows, Atleast I haven't found anything yet

Comment: Just so you know *why* I removed the `at` tag: it is because of how it's defined in the tag wiki - http://superuser.com/tags/at/info

Answer (score 0):

You can call a scheduled task manually by name using the **schtasks** command, like so:

`schtasks /run /TN "your task name"`

I'm not sure if that's what you mean by ID, but the only way to uniquely identify a task in the Task Scheduler (that I know of) is by name.

You can do just about anything with the **schtasks** command. Full documentation is on Microsoft's website [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).